# Turn multiple numbers from my web scraper into a list

Tags: python, web-scraping

When I run this code:

```
for promotion in soup.find_all("div", class_="promo"):
    headline = promotion.text
    headline = re.sub('[^0-9]', '', headline)
    print(headline)
```

It prints out 30 numbers but I am trying to figure out a way to put those numbers into a list so I can take the 5 most recent numbers from it each time the script runs. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Create an empty list before your loop like this: `headline_list = []`. In every iteration, you can append the number to this list with `headline_list.append()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not wrong and if you mean the recent 5 numbers by last 5 numbers in your list this is the code you need.

```
promotion_list = []  # making new list
for promotion in soup.find_all("div", class_="promo"):
    headline = promotion.text
    headline = re.sub('[^0-9]', '', headline)
    print(headline)
    promotion_list.append(headline)  # putting all your 30 items in the new list
for i in range(1, 6):
    print(promotion_list[i * -1])  # this will print the last 5 or recent 5 items
```

Hope you find this code helpful